# Compute shared scalaz Tasks only once

Tags: scala, task, scalaz

I have the following class with Tasks (Scalaz):

```
case class Foo(priceHistory: Task[Vector[Double]], average: Task[Double])
```

The `average` task runs the `priceHistory` task in its computation. What can I do such that the `priceHistory` doesn't compute twice when running both tasks once?

The `average` task:

```
  Task({
    val prices = priceHistory.unsafePerformSync
    prices.foldLeft(0)((acc, p) => acc + p) / prices.length
  })
```

The `priceHistory` task:

```
Task(retrieveData(ticker, from, to))
```

Example call:

```
average.unsafePerformSync // Internally runs priceHistory task
priceHistory.unsafePerformSync // Shouldn't have to be re-run...
```

Comment: Would it help to make priceHistory a lazy value? Otherwise, you are going to have to give us a lot more context to help you.

Comment: I added some context. How should a lazy val work? If I'm not mistaken it would just "wrap" the task again in a delayed computation.

Answer (score 1):

Put your price history into monad, then it will be evaluated once, when you run your task.

```
  case class Foo(priceHistory: Vector[Double], average: Double)
  val priceHistoryTask: Task[Vector[Double]] = ??? 

  val fooTask: Task[Foo] = for {
    prices ← priceHistoryTask
    avg = prices.sum / prices.length
  } yield Foo(prices, avg)
```